# Why I get program not found error on running "npm -v" command with Rust Command::new("npm")?

Tags: npm, rust, command

I am try to testing out version check and other things with Rust `std::process::command`.
Other command are working fine but when I try to call `npm -v`, I got program not found error.

**My Error:**

[image: My Error]

**My Code:**

[image: My Code]

**NPM Test:**

[image: NPM Test]

I want to `npm -v` command runnable with rust

Comment: Please don't post pictures. It was a pure coincidence that I spotted PS and realized it was Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `npm` isn't just `npm`, there's actually multiple (scripts):

- `npm`
- `npm.cmd`
- `npm.ps1`

When you execute `npm` in your terminal, then your terminal is smart and automatically picks the one it recognizes. In the same way that if you (on Windows) execute `foo` it will automatically run `foo.exe`.

However, `Command::new()` does not take this into account. So when it tries to locate `npm` it ends up with `npm` (sh script) and not `npm.cmd`.

You can resolve your issue by changing `"npm"` to `"npm.cmd"`. To have it be a bit more flexible for other operating systems, then you can use a function like this:

```rust
pub fn npm() -> Command {
    #[cfg(windows)]
    const NPM: &str = "npm.cmd";
    #[cfg(not(windows))]
    const NPM: &str = "npm";

    Command::new(NPM)
}
```

Then you simply replace your `Command::new("npm")` with `npm()`.

**Example:**

```rust
use std::process::Command;

pub fn npm() -> Command {
    #[cfg(windows)]
    const NPM: &str = "npm.cmd";
    #[cfg(not(windows))]
    const NPM: &str = "npm";

    Command::new(NPM)
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    npm().arg("-v").spawn()?.wait()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thank you it work! But why not working with direct use like `Command::new("npm.cmd")`.

Comment: You can use `Command::new("npm.cmd")`. It was a suggestion, if you want to future-proof it. Maybe some day you'll run it on Linux or Mac, and using `fn npm()` will ensure it still works